# C++ segmentation error in 2D array assignment

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memory-segmentation

I am receiving segmentation error in the following code. I am not quite aquainted with this error.

```
cout<<"r="<<r<<"c="<<c<<endl;
int i=0,k=0;
for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
    for(int j=0;j<c,str[i]!='0';j++)
        {
         (newl[k][j]=str[i]);  //shows segmentation error on debugging
          cout<<str[i];i++;

        }
```

Could any one point out whats the mistake i am making?

Comment: Could you please show code for `newl` and `str`?

Comment: It's difficult telling what's wrong without seeing what the values of the variables you are depending on are set to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble fellas, turns out i made a sloppy mistake. The condition in second for loop was meant to check null('\0') and I forgot to put the backslash(\). Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'0'` is literally the character for the digit "zero".

The nul-terminator that marks the end of a C-string is `'\0'`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that silly mistake. That,s what working without taking breaks can do!!! :p Simply slipped off my mind.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your code that you are converting 1D array to 2D array.

In this case your maximum index of 1D array should be grater than or equal depend on your requirement to row * column of 2D array.

From the code I can guess that, problem with str[] which is reading the value from out of bound.